# make sql queries in middleware with next js 14?

Tags: next.js

I'm building my own authentication and protected routes process with next js 14.

What I want to do is simple :

- when user is connected, I give him a jwt token and store his token inside my database.

in my middleware what I would like to do is :

- check if my user has token
- check if the token match what I have in my database
- if not redirect to login

That's the first time I use next js and it seems impossible to make SQL query in the middleware.

For now I have this basic code, but obviously this is not secure at all as I can't check the value of the token so the user could just create a cookie with "token" key and would access to my protected routes

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

  const isAuthenticated = request.cookies.get('token')

  
  if(!isAuthenticated) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
  }

}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: '/home',
}
```

I'm using prisma and looks like with local database I can't do it. And I don't want to use "proxy.